# How to dynamically change R .libPaths() based on hostname?

Tags: r

I have two virtual machines running two different versions of GNU/Linux and accessing the same R executable from the same user account.

I'd like to use different libraries depending on the operating system. Right now I'm (un)commenting an `R_LIBS=` environment variable each time I switch systems. Is there a better way to do this?

I tried placing if-then logic in bash syntax based on `uname -n`, but got the following warning:

```
   File /home/wdkrnls/.Renviron contains invalid line(s)
      then
      else
      fi
   They were ignored
```

I take it this file doesn't support programming constructs.

Comment: could you provide the code you are actually executing?

Comment: @TheTime: The home folders are shared between virtual machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
machine_name <- Sys.info()['nodename']

if (machine_name == 'myMachine1') {
   .libPaths(...)
} else {
   .libPaths(...)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you could put it in the .First function of your .Rprofile, or directly in the R code you plan to run

Comment: +1 -- and you can of course do the same in the other resource files to set it via environment variables.